# How to get all redis cache keys in an api to check its working?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, chat

Here is my ConversationObserver code.

```
/**
 * @param Conversation $conversation
 */
public function created(Conversation $conversation)
{
    $messages = Conversation::where('conversation_meta_id', $conversation->conversation_meta_id)
        ->select('conversation_meta_id', DB::raw("DATE(created_at) as date"))
        ->groupBy('conversation_meta_id', 'date')
        ->get();
    Cache::put('messages_' . $conversation->conversation_meta_id, ConversationMessageResource::collection($messages), 300);
}
```

Here is some of my controller api code and i need the lines of code to get all my redis ceche keys in api and want to confirm it working or not?

```
$messages = Conversation::where('conversation_meta_id', $conversation->id)
            ->select('conversation_meta_id', DB::raw("DATE(created_at) as date"))
            ->groupBy('conversation_meta_id', 'date')
            ->get();

    $messages = Cache::remember('messages_' . $conversation->id, 300, function () use ($messages) {
        return ConversationMessageResource::collection($messages);
    });
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. You shouldn't need to get all redis keys to ensure this  is working, you would only need `Cache::has('messages_' . $conversation->id)` to ensure the conversation ends up cached. Its not clear from your problem description why you need all keys

Comment: thanks for the reply ok I am new on redis how can test that conversation messages is being cached like you have mentioned. Can i check it in api resposnse or can print this  Cache::has('messages_' . $conversation->id) to check cached conversation?

Comment: `Cache::has('messages_' . $conversation->id)` should return `true` if that converstation is cached

Comment: yes its returning true. can i see my any cached messages or that's all i can do to check?

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache) to see what you can do using the `Cache::` helper